# Rails last method returns #<Episode:0x007f5661f3a188>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to get the last record from my database table, but when I run this from my controller index method:

```
@a = Episode.last
```

it returns me this:

```
#<Episode:0x007f5661f3a188>
```

Long time ago I wrote code in Rails, so I forget why it happens. Can anyone remind me how to fix it?

But when I print:

```
@a = Episode.all()
```

returns

```
#<Episode::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f567aa10590>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong here.  Episode.last should return an Episode object, and it does.  You could call `.inspect` on the object to see the data inside it.  Or you can access individual columns by name.

Comment: but it returns me something like this: `#<Episode id: 1, tv_series: "\xD0\x9A\xD0\xB0\xD1\x81\xD0\xBB"`

Comment: it's just in russian letters, with english letters it's okay. In the database all looks correctly, but when I select and show, there it look like I show above

Comment: Well, you can get the string with `@a.tv_series` and print it out on your web page.  You may have to take care of character encoding issues if the string in your database does not have an encoding that is compatible with the encoding you are using in the HTML output of your Rails app.  A good strategy is to just use UTF-8 everywhere.  You can debug encoding issues using `String#encoding`, `String#force_encoding`, and `String#bytes`.  It's not clear exactly what problem you are having.  Maybe ask a new question where you show all the relevant code and the expected output vs the actual output.

Comment: please, look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833331/ruby-on-rails-utf8-issue?noredirect=1#comment55432229_33833331