# Ruby on Rails UTF8 issue

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8

When I run my code:

```
@a = People.order('created_at DESC').limit(1).pluck(:name)
```

it returns me this:

```
"\xD0\x9A\xD0\xB0\xD1\x81\xD0\xBB"
```

I read that it's UTF8 issue. For solve this problem I did:

1. My MySQL table is in UTF8 utf8_general_ci
2. In application.rb I paste:

   ```
   class Application < Rails::Application
       config.encoding = "utf-8"
   ```

but all these steps did not help me. In MySQL table all looks correctly and this issue just with the Russian letters.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: have tried to render those string in view instead of seeing it in console?

Answer (score 1):

`"\xD0\x9A\xD0\xB0\xD1\x81\xD0\xBB"` is an ASCII-8BIT string encoded.

It maybe the problem of your console try to display this text. Rails may still render it correctly in view. If not, you can convert it to utf-8 by using `.force_encoding("UTF-8")`:

```
"\xD0\x9A\xD0\xB0\xD1\x81\xD0\xBB".force_encoding("UTF-8")
# => "Касл"
```

Comment: I putted it as `a.force_encoding("UTF-8")` and it returned `undefined method `force_encoding' for ["\xD0\x9A\xD0\xB0\xD1\x81\xD0\xBB"]:Array`

Comment: try `a.first.force_encoding("UTF-8")`

Comment: `force_encoding("UTF-8")` is a method of `String` class. You are calling it on an array. Try `a[0].force_encoding("UTF-8")` or `a.first.force_encoding("UTF-8")`

Comment: yes, it's working now! But can I improve it, that it will return me correct output without force encoding?

Comment: can you show us how you save those string into database?

Comment: as: `People.create(:name => @name).save` where `@name` I parse from a HTML page via Nokogiri

Comment: It seems that this is where the problem come from. Have you tried to place `debugger` before call `People.create` and see data of `@name`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the string value seems to be correct, if you decode it there will be `"Касл"`. So I believe it should work well once you output it into the HTML view.

At the same time, something is probably wrong with your console. Try to run `puts __ENCODING__` in the console, if it doesn't return the `UTF-8` then something is misconfigured with the IRB.

Comment: it returned me `UTF-8`. So, it should work correctly, but I get these symbols

Comment: check what you see in the browser, if you see the correct Cyrillic letters there, then it means that Rails and MySQL are configured correctly. The issue is with console only, and, in that case, that's probably because of an improperly compiled ruby.

Comment: I get these symbols in browser and in the console, but in the console I also get that my encoding is UTF-8

Comment: is your page encoding set to UTF-8? And is the browser set to UTF-8?

Comment: yes. The `force_encoding` works for me, but can I set it up that it will return me correct symbols without force converting?

Comment: Try to add this at the end of your `config/boot.rb` — `Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8;
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8`